# Making a "type anything to continue"?

Tags: java, char

I was making my codes and I thought it would be cool to put a "type anything to continue".
The problem is: I don't know how to do this.
I thought a solution but not as I wanted:

```
char a;

a = scannerName.next().charAt(0);

if (c != (some random character))
{
    game();
}
```

But what I wanted was something different, where instead of you type something and enter, you just type something and it goes to the game method.
I don't know if this is even possible, but anyway, thanks for reading!

Comment: You don't need an if statement to do this, just literally read in a line.

Comment: To get input without pressing enter is actually something controlled by the console, not Java. Depending on your OS, there are ways to put it into a live-input mode (though I don't know how to do it from Java)

Comment: oh and it's referred to as "non-canonical" mode in the UNIX world, if that helps you search.

Comment: It won't work on windows in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a Scanner, it has to be a `"Press <ENTER> to Continue"`, and then you read in the `nextLine()`. You cannot do it so that it will work with single character input. The exception can be if you use a 3rd party console that allows this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that after the user typing anything, the program will just continue with its normal flow. In other words you don't have to check anything (unless you want the user to type something like `"quit"` to finish the program). So you don't need to have a condition. In fact, you can just call `nextLine()` to receive any input and is not necessary to store it in a variable (of course that this depends on what you are trying to do).

```
System.out.println("Type anything to continue (or just ENTER) ");
scannerName.nextLine();

// ... continue with the program
```